# How to POST multipart SOAP XML using JMeter?

Tags: xml, soap, jmeter, multipart

I'm testing mail service using SOAP/XML-RPC request. I need to send multipart XML with attached file (converted to binary). How multipart XML is created in JMeter?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

SOAP/XML-RPC Request is pretty basic element and does not allow for the more complex configuration you need for your test.

You can create an equivalent request using HTTP Request and build it from scratch. You will need add appropriate headers (eg. soap-action) using the HTTP Header Manager config element, and you may also need the HTTP Cookie Manager to handle sessions for you. Put the XML in the Body Data tab/field of the HTTP Request, and use the `Send Files With the Request` fields to include your file[s].